Integrating $\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}}$ two ways gives very different-looking answers. How to show algebraically they differ by a constant?
From Apostol's Calculus Volume 1 2nd ed., 6.22 #46, the task is to integrate
$$\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}}$$
Method 1: The provided hint is to use the substitution $x-a=(b-a)\sin^2(u)$. Thus $b-x=(b-a)\cos^2(u)$ and $dx=2(b-a)\sin u \cos u$. The integral simplifies to
$$\int{\frac{2(b-a)}{|b-a|}du}$$
The result is
$$\frac{2(b-a)}{|b-a|}\;\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{b-a}}} \;+ C \tag1$$
Method 2: I expand the denominator and complete the square, yielding:
$$\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\frac{b+a}{2}\right)^2}}}$$
which results in:
$$\arcsin{\frac{2x-b-a}{|b-a|}} \;+ C \tag2$$
I differentiated both results using Wolfram Alpha and got back the original function. Their graphs are the same, just offset by a constant (1 and 2). These functions differ by only a constant, and yet they are so distinct in appearance! One has a square root inside the arcsin, and one does not.
I am curious to know whether we can algebraically convert one form to the other. I asked Wolfram Alpha to do that it and it failed. Might a reader here have any ideas?

Hint: If $a = \arcsin \sqrt{b}$ (with $0 \leq b \leq 1$), then $b = \sin^2 a$...

@aschepler are we allowed to do this? Aren't we, kind of restricting the values of a?

Oops, I meant to use unrelated variables. If $y = \arcsin \sqrt{x}$, then $x = \sin^2 y$.

For now, let's assume $a < b$, which means that $\frac{b - a}{|b - a|} = 1$. You can examine the $b < a$ case yourself.
Then let $y = \arcsin \sqrt{\frac{x - a}{b - a}}$. With some rearrangement and some basic trig identities, we get:
$$\begin{eqnarray} y & = & \arcsin \sqrt{\frac{x - a}{b - a}} \\
\sin y & = & \sqrt{\frac{x - a}{b - a}} \\
\sin^2 y & = & \frac{x - a}{b - a} \\
\frac{1}{2}(1 - \cos 2y) & = & \frac{x - a}{b - a} \\
\cos 2y & = & 1 - 2 \frac{x - a}{b - a} \\
\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - 2y) & = & 1 - 2 \frac{x - a}{b - a}
\end{eqnarray}$$
I think from there a bit of algebraic manipulation should get you to the required result, and even give you the value of $C$.

Beautiful method. (If you do not mind), you're just two lines from completing the answer though :")

Why didn't you take $y = 2\arcsin \sqrt{\frac{x - a}{b - a}}$?

@BobDobbs Because my first instinct was to simplify just the ugly arcsin term.

An alternate approach that uses a quite useful substitution
I'll use the substitution $x=a\cos^2 y+b\sin^2 y$ and let's call the original integral $I$
Now$(x-a)(b-x)$ can be simplified to $(b-a)^2\sin^2 y\cos^2 y$
Since the integration is indefinite, I'll assume that all mod signs should open with positive sign because I simply have no reason to assume the opposite.
Our integral becomes, $$I=2\int dy$$ $$I=2y+C$$
We also know that $\sin^2 y=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ Now I will assume that everything is in principle interval so I can write $\displaystyle y=\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{b-a}}\right)$
So $$I=2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{b-a}}\right)+C$$

To prove what you want, use the relation $2\sin^2 y=1-\cos(2y)$
